# How to find whether a point is lying inside a square or not in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find whether a point lies inside a square or not. I have been given end coordinates of a diagonal of a square and I have found out the other diagonal's end coordinates.

One method I could think of it was to solve it by using property of circumcircle. I have included all the points inside the circumcircle of the square but I cannot think of a method to exclude the extra points.

**The edges are not parallel to any coordinate axis.**

Is there any method to do it in java?

Heres my part of code:

```
if(distance(x1,y1,x2,y2,j,i)<=dd)
        A[i][j]=1;        
    else
        A[i][j]=0;
```

x1,y1,x2,y2 are the coordinates of the diagonal of the square and dd is the length of diagonal and i,j are the coordinates greater than 0 and less than 100.
I am using array to store the points satisfying the condition.

Comment: This article may help you. http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: For a square whose edges are not necessarily parallel to the coordinate system, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle . Way down the list is an answer about testing whether a point is clockwise or counterclockwise of a vector. Sedgewick's "Algorithms in C" provides pseudocode for this ccw() test, and suggests that polygons of three or four sides are a simpler case than "point in polygon", where it's sufficient just to make this test for each of the sides. [You can find the pseudocode online.]

Comment: Your classmate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407174/

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to do it in Java, but it's simple math.

The equation of a line is:

```
 a * x + b * y = c1   (1)
```

The equation of a line parallel to this is:

```
 a * x + b * y = c2   (2)
```

The equation of two lines perpendicular to these are:

```
-b * x + a * y = c3   (3)
-b * x + a * y = c4   (4)
```

These are the equations of the four edges of the square.

Determine the coefficients of the equations above (`a`, `b`, `c1..c4`) for your square.

The point is inside the square iff both of the following conditions are true:

```
min(c1, c2) <= a * x + b*y <= max(c1, c2)
min(c3, c4) <= -b * x + a * y <= max(c3, c4)
```

Comment: If we can't find any one of the coordinate, then?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I mean to say, if I don't know any one of the coordinates, then can I implement it?

Comment: What is a "coordinate" in the context of your question? Do you mean a corner of the square?

Comment: Yes, I mean a corner of the square

Comment: Then yes. You know the other two edges described by the other 3 corners, so you know the direction of the "missing" edges (the `a` and `b`); and you know that the line must pass through two of the other corners.

Comment: But if it is out of the limit of coordinates then? I have set a limit to x and y if it exceeds that limit then only a part of square is printed or operated upon.

Comment: This is the math. Please think about how to apply it to your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i think you could try to program the manhattan distance from the point to the center of the square and compare it with the manhattan distance from the center of the square to one of the corners , if distance(point,center)< distance (center,limit)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: You can find more info here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry its usually used for discrete numbers distance , but i think u could use it too with float values

Comment: The Manhattan distance isn't relevant: it's the sum of the distances along each of the coordinate axes. Two problems with that: 1) you need to define those coordinate axes; 2) The sum isn't relevant, it's just the maximum of the distance from the centre along the two coordinate axes.