# How do I write a C program to check if a point lies inside a square given end points of one of its diagonal

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I was solving the question stated above but got too confused with the mathematics equations and variables. I started by trying to find coordinates of two other points but the equations could not be solved by me, there ware a lot of variables and I got confused. If that had been completed, I would have tried to check the position of the point with respect to the sides but that would also include a lot of variables and confusion. A good algorithm might just be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't really need a lot of math here.  Draw the square, and observe what happens to the X and Y coordinates of the point as you move it in and out of the square.  Compare the X and Y coordinates of the point with the X and Y coordinates of the two points on the diagonal.

Comment: You should show the sample data, at minimum.  If the points are (0,0) and (3,3) for example, or (2,5) and (4,7), it is all very straight forward because the sides of the square are parallel to the axes.  If the points are (0,0) and (3,6), you need a lot more mathematics to calculate the answer because the square is at a slant.  You should also demonstrate that you've studied enough mathematics to know how to do the calculations. If not, then you need to fix that part of your problem before coming for help with code.  When you know the mathematics involved, then you can start coding a solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The amount of maths needed depends on whether the sides of the square are parallel to the axes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, there's going to be some trig involved unless the slope of the line is 45 degrees.

Comment: Your classmate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402918/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find whether a point is lying inside a square or not in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402918/how-to-find-whether-a-point-is-lying-inside-a-square-or-not-in-java)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I take it back.  You can do the whole job with nothing worse than ordinary arithmetic — if you compare the squares of distances rather than just distances when appropriate.  I have a working (but not remotely efficient) solution based on the area suggestion, and the code uses just the 4 arithmetic operators.  The vector solutions should be better, but I've not coded any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find two remaining points of square:

```
x1 = ?  ;  y1 = ? ;    // First diagonal point
x2 = ?  ;  y2 = ? ;    // Second diagonal point

xc = (x1 + x2)/2  ;  yc = (y1 + y2)/2  ;    // Center point
xd = (x1 - x2)/2  ;  yd = (y1 - y2)/2  ;    // Half-diagonal

x3 = xc - yd  ;  y3 = yc + xd;    // Third corner
x4 = xc + yd  ;  y4 = yc - xd;    // Fourth corner
```

After having four points of square, you can check if the given point lies inside the square then the area of the four triangles as below image will equal the area of square.
[image]

Read more:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506785/given-two-diagonally-opposite-points-on-a-square-how-to-calculate-the-other-two

https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/

Comment: Interesting — the 'other two points' code is simpler than I expected.  It's a while since I last needed to calculate the area of a triangle given the coordinates of the three corners.  Clearly, though, that is calculable (and there's probably a surprisingly simple formula for that, too).

Answer (score 4):

Let's vertices are A and B, and point is P  (accidentally named C at the picture). Find vectors AB, AP, BP

[image]

```
AB.X = B.X - A.X
AB.Y = B.Y - A.Y
and so on
```

P lies inside the square if dot products are non-negative

```
cA = AP x AB    //(AP.X * AB.Y - AP.Y * AB.X)
dA = AP dot AB   //(AP.X * AB.X + AP.Y * AB.Y)
cB = -(AB x BP)
dB = -(AB dot BP)
```

and absolute value of cross products are less then dot products

```
dA >= Abs(cA)
dB >= Abs(cB)
```

(this is equivalent to checking whether angles lie in range `-Pi/4..Pi/4`)

Answer (score 2):

Let assume your problem is **2D** (as in **3D** or **N-D** you would need more information). I would solve it like this:

1. **find 2 missing vertexes**

   So we know `A,B` and want the `C,D`:

   [image: diagonal]

   ```
   M  = (A+B)/2
   v1 = B-M
   ```

   to obtain `v2` we can exploit fact that in **2D** vectors `(x,y)` and `(y,-x)` are perpendicular and the same size so:

   ```
   v2 = (v1y,-v2x)
   ```

   The rest is easy:

   ```
   C = M - v2
   D = M + v2
   ```
2. **compute 2 edge basis vectors**

   [image: basis vectors]

   ```
   U = C-A
   V = D-A
   ```
3. **use dot product to check inside range**

   [image: dot]

   ```
   dot(I,J) = (I.J) = (Ix*Jx) + (Iy*Jy)
   ```

   Gives you the perpendicular projection of `I` into `J` (if both vectors are unit) or the other way around so we can exploit it to detect if point `P` is inside square:

   ```
   W = P-A
   tu = (U.W) / (|U|*|W|)
   tv = (V.W) / (|V|*|W|)
   if ((tu>=0.0)&&(tu<=1.0)&&(tv>=0.0)&&(tv<=1.0)) return inside;
    else return outside;
   ```

Just to be complete abs value of vector is computed like this:

```
    abs(I) = |I| = sqrt ( Ix*Ix + Iy*Iy )
```