# How to draw a square in a 2d matrix given two opposite points

Tags: algorithm, matrix, geometry, 2d

I am given the coordinates of two opposite points of a square (say the points A and C in a square ABCD) and I need to draw the square as ASCII where each character represents a point in a 2D matrix : ' ' (space) for empty and 'X' for full and '\n' is obviously end of line and beginning of the next line. The square might be rotated. How can I do this ?

Now thanks to @avysk's answer in this [SoftwareEngineering Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342826/how-to-draw-a-square-in-a-2d-matrix-given-two-opposite-points), I could determine the 2 missing points of the square (I was apparently asking in the wrong forum as the question was put on hold).

Now I was thinking because the matrix isn't supposed to be too big, I would iterate through every point of the matrix and have a condition such as

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        matrix[y][x] = (in_square(x, y, array_of_4_points)) ? 'X' : ' ';
    }
}
```

I'm missing the logic for the in_square function.

Comment: see [How do I write a C program to check if a point lies inside a square given end points of one of its diagonal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42407174/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with dot products, and there's no need to find B and D.

If you project the point (call it P) onto the diagonal, then if the distance from the point to the diagonal is less than or equal to the distance from the projected point to the closest corner (A or C) then it's inside the square. This assumes "on the line is in".

First, find out how far away from A the point is in the direction of AC. The value must be positive or else the projected point on the diagonal is outside of the segment between A and C.

```
bool in_square(Point P, Point A, Point C)
{
    float dot1 = ((P.x - A.x) * (C.x - A.x)) + ((P.y - A.y) * (C.y - A.y));
    if(dot1 < 0.0f)
        return false;
```

Next, find out how far away from C the point is in the direction of CA and test likewise:

```
    float dot2 = ((P.x - C.x) * (A.x - C.x)) + ((P.y - C.y) * (A.y - C.y));
    if(dot2 < 0.0f)
        return false;
```

Now calculate a vector from a point on the diagonal (e.g. A) to the point P, and then take the dot product of it with a vector perpendicular with the diagonal. This gives the distance of P from the diagonal. Compare this distance to the smallest of dot1 and dot2:

```
    float dot3 = ((P.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y)) + ((P.y - A.y) * (A.x - C.x));
    if(dot3 < 0.0f)
        dot3 = -dot3; // abs value
    if(dot1 < dot2)
        return dot3 <= dot1;
    else
        return dot3 <= dot2;
}
```

There's no need to normalize any of these vectors because we are just doing comparisons and the length of the vectors (AC, CA, perpendicular to AC) is the same each time.